# Delete mysql row when a column is updated

Tags: mysql

My table:

- id
- name
- message
- date
- isSent

What i want is when `isSent` is updated to "2" then delete the whole row 20 seconds later, is this possible?
(it's standard value is 1 but when the message is send it changes to 2)

Comment: Has to be *exactly* 20 seconds later or can it be 20 or more/less seconds later?

Comment: doesn't really matter, if it is atleast 15 seconds then it is ok

Comment: Can you change the structure of the table? To make it work via MySQL, you should split it in half, separating the `isSent` field from the main table.

Comment: I tried doing the one that is now deleted and my phpmyadmin isn't starting up anymore.
maybe it is just a coincidence but my phpmyadmin won't load now lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this (untested) should do the trick but, as @VadzimDvorak stated, it probably need some tweaks on the structure of your tables since it's deleting from the same table that has invoked the trigger.

For sake of having a complete solution, the table should be edited as follow:

Table `mainTable` should contain only the `id`, `name`, `message` and `date` fields, and there should be a second table (`statusTable`) that contains only the `mainId` (a reference to `mainTable.id`) and the `isSent` fields.

The trigger should then be

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER delete_2_after_update
AFTER UPDATE
ON statusTable FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
   SLEEP(20);
   DELETE FROM mainTable WHERE isSent = 2;
END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

*Please* note that this solution requires a change on the structure of your database, which might imply lots of other changes in your program.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a SQL TRIGGER or in PHP with a thread, like that :

```
class My_Thread extends Thread
{

  public function run() {
    sleep(20);
    //DELETE
  }

}

$t = new My_Thread();
$t->start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delay execution with `SELECT SLEEP(<seconds>);`, but you cannot delete invoked row in trigger, so I believe it should be handled outside sql

> A stored function or trigger cannot modify a table that is already
>   being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the
>   function or trigger.
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html#stored-routines-function-restrictions

Answer (score 0):

I would add an extra column that speaks the intent to delete the row at some point, datetime column named `DeleteOn` for example, and I would set value to it when I'm setting `IsSent=2`. Then I would either filter rows where `DeleteOn` shows past date or have a separate periodic process that cleans them up.

This way everyone looking at the table would know that there are rules to this table to auto-delete rows and they could look at when those rows are supposed to disappear.

I prefer this over solution with triggers because of:

- Explicit intent compared to hidden logic in triggers;
- Tendency of developers to forget about triggers when mysterious modifications happen to the data (observed this fenomena in every team I've worked on);
- Countless hours of headaches debugging problems caused by triggers that modify data (because of the point above).